# How to iterate over Future<List> object?

Tags: java, multithreading, list, concurrency

The return value of my `call()` method `List<Person>`. MyCallable class looks like this:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<List<Person>> {

    public List<Person> call() throws Exception {

           ...
    
           return list;
    }

    public MyCallable(List<Account> accountList) {
        super();
    }
}
```

Below is the code I'm writing in my CallableFuture class:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
List<Future<List<Person>>> list = new ArrayList<Future<List<Person>>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Callable<List<Person>> worker = new MyCallable(accountList);
    Future<List<Person>> submit = executor.submit(worker);
    for(Future<List<Person>> :list){
        //list.add(submit);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to iterate over `list` and add `submit` to it. Am i doing this right?

Comment: I'm confused by your `//list.add(submit)` bit. Are you trying to add to the list that the `Callable` made? Generally the pattern with Futures is that the Callable creates a fully-formed thing (in this case, your `List<Person>`), and then someone else creates `get()` on the Future in order to get that fully-formed thing -- not to add to it. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is no point iterating over a list while you are building it. I suggest iterating over it only after you have added all the future objects to it.

Answer (score 5):

Couple of problems. First of all, rather than attempting to grab the results of the `Future` immediately after submitting each one (if you do this you're essentially just serializing everything and defeating the purpose), submit *all* of them, and *then* retrieve the results:

```
List<Future<List<Person>>> list = new ArrayList<Future<List<Person>>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Callable<List<Person>> worker = new MyCallable(accountList);
    Future<List<Person>> submit = executor.submit(worker);
    list.add(submit); // just keep track of them
}

// NOW the next step is to get the results...
```

Next, you're having some basic syntax problems. In general to iterate over the items in a container the syntax is:

```
List<A> list = ...;

for (A a : list) {
   // do things with 'a'
}
```

And finally, you need to check the docs for [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()), which show you how to wait for it to be computed and obtain the results by using `Future#get()`.

Putting this all together you end up with the next step (after submitting everything as above) being:

```
// ... all tasks submitted and 'list' now contains the Futures, next step:

for (Future<List<Person>> future : list) {
    List<Person> result = future.get(); // wait for task to complete
    // 'result' is now the List<Person> returned from the corresponding callable.
}
```

The idea behind submitting everything *then* getting all the results is you now allow your tasks to execute concurrently instead of waiting for each one to complete before adding the next. Then, at the end, even if you end up waiting on a few, it's OK, because the *total* wait time for all tasks has been reduced as intended.

Comment: I guess there is a gap in my understanding. Thanks @Jason , thats very helpful.

Comment: @zachandcode Submitting a callable puts it on a queue of things to be executed in the background, `submit()` returns immediately, probably before the task is actually executed. A `Future` represents a result that you're expecting to be available at some unknown point in the future, after the background task completes. `Future#get()` pauses and waits for that task to complete and the result to be available.

Comment: So it's like splitting a grocery list among some helpful friends at the store: You tell them all what to get, all at once, and say "go, team!", then you wait for them all to go get the stuff and come back. If you just go down the list one item at a time and wait for that friend to go find it and come back before moving on to the next item, you might as well just do it all yourself, because you're not saving any time.

Comment: Makes sense. @Jason, do you have an open line where you take novice questions? Stupid questions? :)

Comment: @zachandcode Well you could ask questions on this site and you might be able to get help in [the chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). But one of the big community philosophies here is encouraging folks to make a good effort on their own before coming here, so don't forget about good resources like the official tutorials at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ and the official API documentation, as well as questions that already exist on this site!